# Azure Service Principal - force expiration on purpose?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, service-principal

Azure Service Principals have an expiration date by default and have the need to be rotated.

But is there a way to invalidate or force expiry of a service principal?

Comment: You can delete client secret

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The credentials used when a service principal authenticates can be stored either on the service principal itself, or on the backing application object (i.e. the "app registration").

Changing the expiration date of an existing credential is not currently supported. If you wish to disable a credential, you should delete it. (If you wish to re-enable it, you can simply add it back in as an authorized credential.)

## Remove a credential from an application (app registration)

### Using the Azure portal

1. Navigate to Azure Active Directory > App registrations > (choose the app) > Certificates & secrets
2. Next to any certificate or client secret, choose the "Delete" icon (️)

   [image: Certificates & secrets in the Azure portal]

### Using Azure AD PowerShell

To [remove a key credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/azuread/remove-azureadapplicationkeycredential?view=azureadps-2.0) (certificate):

```bsh
Remove-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential -ObjectId "{id}" -KeyId "{key-id}"
```

To [remove a password credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/azuread/remove-azureadapplicationpasswordcredential?view=azureadps-2.0) (client secret):

```bsh
Remove-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredentia -ObjectId "{id}" -KeyId "{key-id}"
```

### Using Microsoft Graph

To [remove a key credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/application-removekey?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) (certificate):

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{id}/removePassword
Content-type: application/json

{
    "keyId": "{key-id}"
}
```

To [remove a password credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/application-removepassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) (client secret):

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{id}/removePassword
Content-type: application/json

{
    "keyId": "{key-id}"
}
```

## Remove a credential from a service principal

### Using the Azure portal

It is not currently possible to use the Azure portal to manage credentials stored directly on the service principal.

### Using Azure AD PowerShell

To [remove a key credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/azuread/remove-azureadserviceprincipalkeycredential?view=azureadps-2.0) (certificate):

```bsh
Remove-AzureADServicePrincipalKeyCredential -ObjectId "{id}" -KeyId "{key-id}"
```

To [remove a password credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/azuread/remove-azureadserviceprincipalpasswordcredential?view=azureadps-2.0) (client secret):

```bsh
Remove-AzureADMSApplicationPassword -ObjectId "{id}" -KeyId "{key-id}"
```

### Using Microsoft Graph

To [remove a key credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/serviceprincipal-removekey?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) (certificate):

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{id}/removeKey
Content-type: application/json

{
    "keyId": "{key-id}"
}
```

To [remove a password credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/serviceprincipal-removepassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) (client secret):

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{id}/removePassword
Content-type: application/json

{
    "keyId": "{key-id}"
}
```

Comment: Is it correct to infer that the expiry date as shown in your image - [11/18/2020] - cannot be controlled/modified? For instance - is there a way for me to shorten the validity of it without deleting the credential ?

Comment: No, you cannot do this, you'd have to remove it and add it again with a different expiration time. Can you share why you want to force expiration (rather than just removing it)?

Comment: Wanted to check if there is  Time To Live - level control for this as provided by credentials generated with other 3rd party integrations. Thanks for your conclusive answer!

Comment: "If you wish to re-enable it, you can simply add it back in as an authorized credential" - How can I do this?